# How to avoid connection errors?

Tags: everscale

we encountering a 401 error on connecting to the main-net.
What is the way to avoid this error? We've already created a project on the dashboard and have added the Authorisation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient and fastest way to integrate with Everscale is https://github.com/broxus/ever-wallet-api

This is a light node + api for sending and tracking payments.
The app listens for addresses from the database and indexes all transactions, putting information about them in the postsgres DB. Also it send webhooks to your backand on incoming transfers